# jQuery and HTML5 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering whether or not jQuery supports HTML5 elements.

For example, I tried this code but it fails with a rather weird error:

```
$('<progress value="2">').val();
```

It says:

```
TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'replace'
```

Is jQuery to support HTML5 elements in the future, or am I doing something wrong this way?

**EDIT:** It does not seem to be the selector: http://jsfiddle.net/z5t3g/

Comment: you have to reference html elements like $('progress'), i think you can then select based on the value as well.

Comment: Appreantly, using HTML for the element and then accessing it with `$('#progress')` doesn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/z5t3g/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your `<progress />` element in the DOM:

```
<progress value="2" />
```

You can select it using jQuery, but it seems that (as of version 1.5) it doesn't know to return the `value` attribute using the `.val()` method. You need to check the attribute by name:

```
$('progress').attr('value');
```

Comment: @pimvdb - That fiddle works for me -> Value 50 is inserted to div#div (Firefox 3.6)

Comment: Really? Then it's a Chrome bug I guess... Edit: I had to close the `</progress>`, and I had to use `attr('value')`. Then it works!

Comment: Great! Out of curiosity, does it work with self-closing tag `<progress />`? In your fiddle it was missing the closing `/` and I don't have Chrome installed.

Comment: No, only `</progress>` works. I tried `/>` to no avail. (On Chrome at least...)

Comment: I just checked it again and for some reason it does work with `/>` or just without closing in Chrome... I must have been doing something wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/z5t3g/9/

Comment: Chrome does auto-update, so if this was a bug introduced in a previous version, they might have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#progress').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a jquery selector for it

```
$("progress").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do this

```
$('progress[value=="2"]).val();
```

You can't select using the entire tag with jQuery.